# Best Web Framework for Future Mobile App?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, cross-platform, mobile

I am in the planning stages of making a new *simple* web application. By simple I mean something with login capabilities and standard CRUD functions. No graphics or super complicated code behind the scenes.

**My goal is to develop just the website right now and then expand to an Android and iOS app later down the road.**

Which frameworks would work for this? I am thinking Angular because most Udemy courses that I see teaching how to build connected websites and mobile apps use NativeScript. And NativeScript seems to work best with Angular. But I just have no idea.

I have made websites with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP (some MVC PHP frameworks), and WordPress. But I have never made an app before so I don't have much experience in this domain.

Comment: "Best" is always subjective – and the one that *works best **for you.*** What might fit your needs is also hard to tell if it's not clear what features your app shall have, what platforms you target, etc. I'm no dev, but I'm afraid we lack details for good recommendations (and no, SE sites are not about "opinions". [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154) and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154), so we won't just "list names" here. And websites work in browsers, of which there are many available on mobiles ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you. I have edited my question to remove the word "best" so that it is less opinion based and more just "tell me what options I have". Because like I said I have no clue about the mobile app side of things. And I have been trying to find an answer to this question on multiple Reddit communities and on here but nothing yet...

Comment: @Izzy I have also added some of the features I need.

Comment: Thanks (though you've missed the "best" in the title :) Let's leave it to those familiar with the topic to ask what specific details they might need then. IIRC the term for what you're after is "PWA", so while waiting for our specialists you might wish to peak into the [Wipikedia article on "Progressive Web Application"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application), which might give you some clues. Good luck!